# Why my index is not used in a mysql selection

Tags: mysql, indexing

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`title`,`from_date`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employees.titles WHERE emp_no < '10010' and title='Senior Engineer';
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titles | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   16 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

My question is why only the first column can use the index? I know many article/doc give that conclusion but I'd like to know the detail explanation.

My understanding is, MySQL can scan the BTREE index and find a collection of keys that match  `emp_no < '10010'` and then filter them on `title='Senior Engineer'`, why it said that the `from_data` column can not use index? (BTW I think I know how B+ Tree works).

Thanks.

---

Below is output of explain format=json:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1.41"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "titles",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY"
      ],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "emp_no"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.21",
        "eval_cost": "0.20",
        "prefix_cost": "1.41",
        "data_read_per_join": "168"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "emp_no",
        "title",
        "from_date",
        "to_date"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`employees`.`titles`.`emp_no` < '10010') and (`employees`.`titles`.`title` = 'Senior Engineer'))"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your table is very small, even when index reduce your search cost, using the index also have a cost itself.

So for small tables the cost of using the index is bigger than just read the whole table. Try to include more rows and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 'emp_no' < ... AND ...
KEY(emp_no, ...)
```

Since `emp_no` is being used in a "range" ("<"), only `emp_no` of the key will be used.

By turning the key around:  `(title, emp_no, ...)`, both `title` and `emp_no` can be used.

[*Cookbook on indexing*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

But note...  This index change will make *this* `SELECT` work 'better'.  But what *other* queries do you have?  You *may* need to have more than one index, perhaps:

```
PRIMARY KEY(emp_no, title, from_date),
INDEX(title, emp_no)
```

Back to your original question.  The `EXPLAIN` *does* show that it is using a "range".  But it does not say whether `title` is being checked.  What version of MySQL are you using?  Newer versions have "index condition pushdown", which would sort of do the test on `title` that you mention.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` should say whether it is doing such.

Still, having an index *starting* with `title` is more efficient because it does not need to tediously step over titles that don't apply.  *All* the relevant rows are consecutive.

**Edit** Explaining the `EXPLAIN`

It says that it is using a "range", and using ("used_key_parts") only the `emp_no` part of the index.  Yet it says that the "used_columns" is all 4 columns, even more than what is in the KEY it is using.  To explain...

The `PRIMARY KEY` in InnoDB is 'clustered' with the data -- that is, they are in the *same* BTree.

The execution will use only `emp_no < '10010'` -- It will start at the beginning of the table and go up to, but no including, the first row with `emp_no = '10010'`.  As it goes, it (specifically, the InnoDB engine) will apply the "attached condition" "((`employees`.`titles`.`emp_no` < '10010') and (`employees`.`titles`.`title` = 'Senior Engineer'))" to filter out any rows that fail that test.  (This is where I say it is "stepping over" uninteresting `title` values.)

It is scanning the "data" BTree.  If you add `INDEX(title, emp_no)`, you will probably find quite a different JSON.  Post it; I will explain.

(Note:  If "too many" emps are 'Senior Engineers', the optimizer may decide to scan the data instead of using the new index.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link, MySQL version is 5.7.10--the latest, json output attached, but I think the key_length show all the info. You suggestion is good, but I'm not tuning the query here, it's a contrived example and I just want to know why.

Comment: But you mentioned "consecutive" in your last sentence, maybe that's the reason it did not "step over".

Comment: See "Explaining the EXPLAIN".